# How to bypass a unique constraint exception in JPA 2

Tags: jpa, oracle10g, eclipselink

I have a JPA entity with a composite unique key, and I wrote a scheduler that loads data into the table of this entity. Only that I have an exception when load in in case there is a unique key violation. I want to suppress any unique constraint violation exception from my database and continue the loading of all the other objects. I am using transactions, and I would not want to lock the whole table to verify uniqueness as other users are using it.

Comment: explain what you mean 'its not working'.  What isn't working about it?  If you are getting a constraint exception though, the persistence unit is in an inconsistent state - it doesn't know what statements or objects might have lead to the error and so cannot be used.  You need to fix the problem and retry in a new context/transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can iterate over all objects and wrap the method that load an object into table by a 
`try{} catch(JPAException exp){}`

With this if the exception occurred when load any particular data, the iteration will continue and other objects still be processed.

Comment: I tried `try{} catch(SQLException exp){continue;}` and even `try{} catch(Exception exp){continue;}` but it's not working.